# Build html parts from value of a js function

Tags: javascript, html

I really don't know how to put that in words correctly, sorry if the title misleads.

I have a function in a js file, which checks if an element is in a data array. If so the html page should show all the values of the element (so far so good). But if the element is not in the array, my html page should only display: Element not found.

js function:

```
function containsID(arr, number) {
    var i = arr.length;
    while (i--) {
       if (arr[i].id === number) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

html:

```
{% if containsID(data, id) %} //I want something like that
    <p>{{data[id].text}}</p>
{% else %}
    <p> Not found </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Could you please post the array and the object?

Comment: array simplified: {"id":0,"text":"text"},{"id":1,"text":"text2"}

and which object?

Comment: Whatever you have passed as the second argument, it looks like you might be comparing an object to an integer, arr[anything].id in the example being an integer

Comment: no, it used to be an object, but now a call would look like this: containsID(arr,1)

Comment: https://codepen.io/mrbizle/pen/dRoXXp So the JavaScript appears to work, are you passing your array in square brackets []? Does liquid need a strict comparator? eg containsID(data, id) === true ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   var desiredLogic = function(id){
         var itemWithGivenId = arr.filter( x=> {  return x.id === id } );
           if ( itemWithGivenId.length ) {
               document.createElement("p").innerText = itemWithGivenId.text;
               //append this element wherever you want to see it on the page
              }
          else{
             document.createElement("p").innerText = "Not found";
             //append this element wherever you want to see it on the page
              }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the index of the item with given ID

```
function containsID(arr, obj) {
  var i = arr.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (arr[i].id === obj) {
       return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

I am not sure what {% %} annotation stands for (looks like some template engine), but your html should by something like this:

```
{% if containsID(data, id) >= 0 %} //I want something like that
  <p>{{data[containsID(data, id)].text}}</p>
{% else %}
  <p> Not found </p>
{% endif %}
```

better is to store the result of containsID in some template variable and then use it twice (once in condition, once in output) to avoid looping the array two times

Comment: regarding the {% %}: Yep, when I learned HTML, my teacher used the Liquid template engine, so I'm used to it

Answer (score 0):

To output something from Javascript in HTML you can set the innerHTML value of an element.

```js
function getElement(e) {
    return document.getElementById(e);
}

function foo() {
    getElement("output").innerHTML = "Foo";
}

function bar() {
    getElement("output").innerHTML = "Bar";
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
    &nbsp;
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="foo()" value="Foo">
<input type="button" onclick="bar()" value="Bar">
```